# Why the passive form is wrong here?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> On the other hand, paper-based books are more difficult **to be stored
>   \ to store** than electronic books.

A [research](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficult%20to%20be%20stored%2Cdifficult%20to%20store&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficult%20to%20store%3B%2Cc0) using Google Ngram shows that the passive form "difficult to be stored" is never used but I cannot understand the rule here. **Could you please help me to analyse this?**

Comment: Neither of these is the passive.

Comment: @PeterFlom
I think it is wrong structure but why "be stored" is not passive? or how it is wrong?

Comment: "Paper-based books are more difficult to store than electronic books" is intransitive; there is no direct object, so it can't be passivized..

Comment: @BillJ I don't get it. What is the wrong in "the book is stored" and how this differs from "paper-based books are more difficult to be stored".  I'm positive the last one is wrong but I am not sure how to analyse it.

Comment: Because the adjective "difficult" resists having a passive clause as its complement. The result is unnatural, as you can see.

Comment: It's not just the adjective/complement agreement: "It is difficult to be wronged."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277710/to-infinitive-used-after-adjective

Comment: Exactly.  It's about if the adjective determines its referent as the *subject* or the *object* of the verb.  "Mary is easy to see."   "Mary is happy to see."  Besides the "it" test you can also try to see if the adjective can be turned into an adverb with -ly and shift to past tense:   "Mary is easily seen." or the adjectival phrase can take a receiver:  "Mary is happy to see you."

Comment: The reason this seems like it might be related to "passive voice" is because in the passive voice we don't specify an explicit subject, so constructions with the first kind of adjective (control adjectives) are more like to make sense in that sort of sentence.  But that's not the rule at work here; the fact that some adjectives modify the actions of their referents and others modify actions done to their references is.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sentences

> 1) Storing paper-based books is more difficult than (storing) electronic books. 2) To store paper-based books is more difficult...

In this case "storing" or "to store" is a gerund - A verb form (the present participle or infinitive) used as a noun, in this case, the subject of the sentence. But since storing is being used as a noun, you can't make it passive.

I'm not sure this is an answer, but it is a least an analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As BillJ says in a comment, *difficult* resists taking a passive infinitive complement.

But I think this is primarily a semantic restriction. When you use *difficult to X*, the presumption is that the subject of *X* is the entity who experiences difficulty:

> I find it difficult to walk slowly.

So if you used a passive:

> Paper-based books are difficult to be stored

it means that the books are finding it difficult, not that you are.

With suitable verbs and context, you can use a passive infinitive:

> It is difficult to be heard, with all this noise around.

I don't think this is very common - most people would say something different, such as *It is difficult to make yourself heard*; but it is possible.

You can, of course, also say

> It is difficult to hear, with all this noise around.

but that is from the perspective of the hearer, rather than the speaker.